# Is there a way to skip the first evaluation of an SVA?

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I have the following property:

```
property p_0;
 $rose(signal_a) |-> $rose(signal_b) ;
endproperty
```

my problem is, after HW RST, signal_b rises (normal behavior) but the assertion fails, and I want this check to be evaluated only later.

I wanted to work with **first_match()** with something like below:

```
p_0_a : assert property ( ! first_match(p_0)) else `uvm_fatal(...)
```

so that I skip the first match of this property but the compiler generates a syntax error.

Is there a way to skip the evaluation of SVAs after specific number of iterations?

Comment: A good question, to which I think I have a solution (cascaded implication). However, before I answer, there is something I don't understand: if a reset causes `signal_b` to rise, why would that cause the assertion to fail? The test for `signal_b` rising is in the consequent, not the antecedent, so `signal_b` rising at some other time should never cause your assertion to fail. Do you mean "after HW RST, signal_a rises (normal behavior)" ?

Comment: Hi Matthew,
thanks for the interaction. There is other mechanism in the property that monitors if `signal_b` has risen without `signal_a` being asserted. The fail msg is like " **Unexpected signal_b rising edge** " 
So, I simplified the property just for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cascaded implication operators* may well help you out, for example something along the lines of:

```
assert property (reset |-> p_0);
```

Basically, |=> and |-> are right-associative:

```
A |=> B |=> C
```

means

```
A |=> ( B |=> C )
```

ie If `A` happens, check `(B |=> C)` immediately afterwards. If `A` does not happen, don't check `(B |=> C)`.